# Form won't submit in an iframe in a modal window using javascript without returning in Safari

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, safari, modal-dialog

I have a .aspx page that opens a modal window which uses an iframe to load a second .aspx page that creates a form, some text areas and a button that submits the form.

The problem is that in Safari 5 for Windows 7 (and SOMETIMES Chrome) the form doesn't seem to submit unless a return happens.

If CloseModal() happens first, then the page closes without the data being saved.
If return happens first, then the data saves and the window does not close.

Apologies if I'm missing something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

```
function SubmitFunction()
{
    var objForm = document.getElementById("MyForm");
    if(objForm.IsValid())
    {
        objForm.submit();
        parent.CloseModal('',1);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

function CloseModal(ReturnValue,LoadSource,ReturnType)
{
    if(window.showModalDialog)
    {
        window.returnValue = ReturnValue;
        if(opener)
        {
            if(ReturnType == STRING_ARGUMENT_URL && ReturnValue)
            {
                opener.location.href = ReturnValue;
            }
            else if(LoadSource)
            {
                opener.location.reload();
            }
        }
        window.close();
    }       
    else
    {
        window.returnValue = ReturnValue;
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: We ended up having to wait until the page reloads and evaluate a variable that is one state by default and another after the form is submitted.

I'm still unsure why this was a Safari "only" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up having to wait until the page reloads and evaluate a variable that is one state by default and another after the form is submitted. I'm still unsure why this was a Safari "only" issue.